# Reword one commit prior to merge

Tags: git

So my git history looks something like this:

```
*
|
*
|\
| \
*  * <- The one I want to reword.
|  |
*  *
| /
|/
*
|
*
```

And I want to reword the commit message at the location marked above. I have tried, `rebase -i` and `rebase -i -p`, but in both cases, I'll have to fix all the merge conflicts in the next commit, which I really don't want to do. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: You can't reword that commit without also generating a new merge commit with a new commit ID, you're rewriting history and all subsequent history will be altered.

Comment: I have no problem with that. I just don't want to re-do all the merge conflicts. This is a private branch, so all sorts of history re-writings are okay.

Comment: I think you want `git rerere`: "reuse recorded resolution of conflicted merge".

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you provide an answer for this use case, based on that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, checkout to the merged commit, copy the files with conflict
  (or all the files).
- Rebase interactively as you did it.
- Copy back the files when you reached the merged commit.
- Finish the interactive rebasing.

Comment: Haha. That's precisely what I was doing right now. Sort of feels like cheating, but it works. I'll wait a little to see if a more "proper" answer comes up, and if not, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.